# Can not use is.na() function in mutate_if funciton in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I tried to use `is.na()` in `mutate_if()` but I get an error:

> Error in is_logical(.p) : object 'n_day' not found

`n_day` indeed in my dataframe and I thought because of the argument set of `is.na()` that I can not use it in `mutate_if()` but I don't know how to solve it.

Here's the idea if the value in `n_day` is `NA`, replace it with the value in `n_cum` at the same day.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

My code like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

t <- structure(list(city = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                       1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
                    time = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 
                                       3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("2012/1/1", "2012/1/2", 
                                                                           "2012/1/3", "2012/1/4", "2012/2/1", "2012/2/2", "2012/2/3", 
                                                                           "2012/2/4"), class = "factor"), n_cum = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                     5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                   -16L))
t

t2 <- t %>% group_by(city) %>% 
  mutate(n_day = n_cum - lag(n_cum))

t2 %>% mutate_if(is.na(n_day), n_day = n_cum)
```

Comment: t2 <- t %>% group_by(city) %>% 
  mutate(n_day = if_else(is.na(lag(n_cum)),n_cum,n_cum - lag(n_cum))) . 

Hope it helps. You don't need to use mutate_if.

Answer (score 1):

`mutate_if` is used to do operations on multiple columns at once([See documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html)), this is not what you are looking for here as you only want to change one column.

The question can be solved using `mutate` and `if_else` :

```
t2 %>% mutate(n_day = if_else(is.na(n_day),n_cum,n_day))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mutate_at` + `if` condition instead,

```r
t2 %>% mutate_at(vars(n_day), ~ ifelse(is.na(.), n_cum, .))
```

In the case of multiple variables selection, just add them respectively into `vars` helper.